# Searching in Postgres in multiple fields

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I am working on a Spring-MVC project using Hibernate as ORM and PostgreSQL as the database. In the project, I would like to search somee products in the database. As you can guess, the products have quite a few parameters like productName, productDescription, productTags, etc. 
Question : I am looking for a search function in HQL preferably where all the fields are searched and the productList is returned. I have a simmple search function as mentioned below.

Search function :

```
public List<ProductBasic> listProduct(Productname) {

    if(session == null){
        session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    } else{
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    Query query = session.createQuery("from ProductBasic as p where p.productName=:productName order by p.ordernumber");
    query.setParameter("productName",productName);
    List<ProductBasic> productBasicList= query.list();
    return productBasicList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply compare your search string with multiple fields

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from ProductBasic as p where p.productName=:searchString or p.productDescription = :searchString order by p.ordernumber");
```

Comment: Simple, thank you. This helps. :-)  Do I have to setParameter only once?

Comment: @Akshay Yes, only once.

Comment: Can you inshort tell me how to get only first 50 results?

Comment: @Akshay `query.setMaxResults(50)`

Comment: Thank you. I can accept your answer in 8 minutes(Stackoverflow says that). I will do it. Just last thing, so do I have to write some additional code to get the next 50 results. Like I searched, and I have a display with Ajax, so the user scrolls down and wants to see the next 50 results, what can I do then?

Comment: @Akshay You combine `setMaxResults()` with `setFirstResult()` to implement paging. So, for first page it would be `first = 0, max = 50`, second page `first = 50, max = 50` (double check the numbers, to be sure no row is skipped or doubled).

Comment: Hello, I tried the query below, doesnt seem to to worrk :  Query query =  session.createQuery("from ProductBasic as p where p.productname=:productdescription or p.productdescription=:productdescription").setMaxResults(50); I can only get results when String to search matches productname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65619/discussion-between-predrag-maric-and-akshay).

Answer (score 0):

In the long run, the best thing to do is to create a column (or perhaps even another table) for search terms. I personally like full text search using the tsvector datatype..

Basically you have a trigger that appends all of your data together and saves it in a tsvector field (or just a text field, but it's bigger). The trigger rebuilds this on update or delete.

you call your field "search"
and you can simply do a "where search like '%term%'"

you can speed this all up using either full text search txvector indexes, or using trigrams-- both of which will also allow queries where no exact match is found, but it'll return similar results. With full text, case doesn't matter and you can even find synonyms, etc.. 
Let me know if you're interested and I'll post some example code.